# Angular - Assign/Store a Selected Option to Scope Variable For Use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-select

I have a select option with the options of yes or no.

```
<select ng-model="selectedAnsw" ng-options="answ.text for answ in answs"></select>

$scope.answs = [
            {
                text: "Yes",
                value: Yes
            },
            {
                text: "No",
                value: no
            } ];
```

I want to store what the user selects in `$scope.selectedAnsw` and have it save + populate the select.  So if the user selects `No` and then navigates to a different page and comes back to yes/no page `No` is preselected because they selected it a bit ago/it was stored.  I don't need to keep the selection forever, just during this session.  Thinking this might have to do with $rootScope + ng-select.

Comment: Use a provider (factory or service)

Comment: So to be clear, this is NOT a single page application? It's an Angular app with multiple html pages?

Comment: don't use `$rootScope` for this, `$rootScope` is not meant to be a dumping ground for data you want to use in multiple views.....

Comment: @azium - Angular app with multi pages.

Comment: I think the point @azium is trying to make is that **views** are not the same as **pages**, and you should be clear which is which.

Comment: Then you'll need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage save the values there and load them at the top of your service / controller.

Comment: @azium - Sorry different Views

Comment: Then you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers

Comment: @azium yes, a provider :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **service** to achieve this. Create a service with setter and getter methods. Inject the service in your controller.

Now whenever user selects any option set it in service using setter, and when user comes back to same page, use getter method to get the user selection.

For setting it back to your select box you can take the object from your service and directly assign it to your `ng-model`.

For e.g

`$scope.selectedAnsw = yourServiceValue`

Below is simple snippet explaining the use of service.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

app.controller("testCntrl", function($scope, storeData) {
  $scope.selectedAnsw = {};

$scope.answs = [
            {
                text: "Yes",
                value: "Yes"
            },
            {
                text: "No",
                value: "no"
            } ];
  
  $scope.getAns = function() {
    $scope.userAns =  storeData.getUserAns();
  }
  
  $scope.setAns = function(ans) {
    storeData.setUserAns(ans);
  }
})
.service("storeData", function(){
  this.setUserAns = function(ans) {
    this.ans = ans;
  }
  
  this.getUserAns = function() {
    return this.ans;
  }
})
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="testCntrl">
<select ng-model="selectedAnsw" ng-options="answ.text for answ in answs" ng-change="setAns(selectedAnsw)">
     <option value="" disabled>Select An Answer</option></select>
</select>
  <div>User Selected : {{selectedAnsw}}</div>
  
  <button ng-click="getAns()">Show user selection</button>
  <div>User had Selected : {{userAns}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```